# Listing Box cloud storage files via WebDAV on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, cloud, webdav, box-api

I've tried to mount Box cloud storage on my Ubuntu via WebDAV and it works. But the only thing is I need to download the files (whole file, all files) on to my computer to view files in the cloud. That is so bandwidth hungry and wasting time. Is it any possible solution to only list files instead of downloading the whole file? Like the Dropbox app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that's what you're asking, but you can see the children of a directory / collection (and hence list the files) by using WebDAV's [PROPFIND method](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html#METHOD_PROPFIND).

Comment: What I mean is every time when I started to mount the WebDAV folder, system monitor shows that my computer is downloading files from the Box server, it doesn't save a copy in my hard disk. So every time I mount it, it downloads. I know there may not have a proper solution for this until a client is created, just wanna find is there any hope left. It's okay no, I just stop using the WebDAV mounting way, I just use the webpage for Box. Thanks for answering anyways.